# How to package ReactJs app with Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: java, reactjs, maven, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am wondering is there any way to combine REST API and UI of Spring boot Webflux application. I use React for the UI part.

In normal Spring MVC application I can use **frontend-maven-plugin** along with **maven-resources-plugin** to build and copy the static resources to target directory. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.15.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack build dev</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run webpack:build</arguments>
                            <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>position-react-build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${frontendSrcDir}/build</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Everything works fine. But it is maybe because I use embedded Tomcat Server (default for Spring Boot with Spring MVC).

For the second approach, I would like to use Spring Boot Webflux. By default the application will run on Netty. I tried to apply the same maven configuration. But when the application is started it does not handlethe ReactJs application.